# Which user own the postgres process?

Tags: postgresql, system-administration

I installed the `postgresql` rdbms using standard:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

and now I can see the binary:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres
```

which means the `root` user own it.

HOWEVER: in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-createdb.html)

> You will need to become the operating system user under which PostgreSQL was installed (usually postgres)

I had to switch to `postgres` user to be able to connect to the server to create new `role` with my name.

So can anyone explain this contradiction? Or am i missing something?

Comment: Do `sudo ls -al /var/lib/postgresql/12/main/` and you will see that the Postgres cluster is run as `postgres.postgres`. If that does not work use `pg_lscluster` to see what the `Cluster` name is and use that instead of `main` in the `ls`. FYI, you do not need to switch to the system user `postgres` to connect to the server. Just do `psql -d <db_name> -U <db_user>`, in your case `postgres` for `<db_user>`.

Comment: The command show `postgres.postgres` but I didn't understand what was going here, if you can turn your comment to an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: The documentation is not totally accurate. It should be "the user with which `initdb` was run".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

`sudo apt-get install postgresql`

it is installing the package(postgresql) files as the `root` user. The install will also create a system user `postgres`. When the server cluster is created it will be done with the files assigned the `postgres` user rights per [Create cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html) and it will be run as the `postgres` user per [Running server](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/server-start.html). In fact Postgres will refuse to run as the `root` user. To see what user the server is running as do:

`ps aux | grep postgres`

Now in addition to the system user `postgres` a database user `postgres` is also created. It is not strictly necessary to become the system user `postgres` to connect to the database, all you need to do is connect as the database user `postgres` by using `-U postgres` with `psql`.

FYI, the use of the name `postgres` as the user is a convention and not a requirement, so you may see some exceptions in other packaging systems. For instance the MacOS package [postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/) makes the name the system user name you installed as.

Comment: Thank you very much.